# How to get data from array to string JAVA?

Tags: java

I have an array that looks like this:

```
ss="date:03/27/2017,text=sample,date:03/28/2017"
```

But I want the just `03/27/2017` from array into one string
How it is possible in JAVA?

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. Also, have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: array or string separated by commas?

Comment: that's some strange array

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) method, take a look:

```
String ss="date:03/27/2017,text=sample,date:03/28/2017";
String date = ss.split(",")[2].split(":")[1];
System.out.println(date);//03/28/2017
```

### Step-by-step

```
ss.split(",");//[date:03/27/2017, text=sample, date:03/28/2017]
ss.split(",")[2];//date:03/28/2017
ss.split(",")[2].split(":");//[date, 03/28/2017]
ss.split(",")[2].split(":")[1];//03/28/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to extract every date in the String or if is an array you can convert it to a String and then apply this pattern to find the matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}+/\\d{2}+/\\d{4}+");
String ss = "date:03/27/2017,text=sample,date:03/28/2017";
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ss);
while(matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println(ss.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
}
```

Hope this help